# Convert latin letters to equivalent decimal value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I intend to convert latin characters like À ,Ü and so on to it equivalent decimal value. For example Ü has decimal value of 220.

I tried by using parseInt("Ü") but it is returning NAN. 
Is there anyway I can get the Decimal value of this character using JavaScript.
Any help will is truly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try native [*CharCodeAt*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt)

```
"Ü".charCodeAt() //returns 220
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this-

```
var codeA ="Ü".charCodeAt();
```

you can follow [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charCodeAt.asp) link also-